# What wrong is in my code that the error keeps on increasing with every iteration of gradient descent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent

The code below reads a csv (Andrew NG ML course ex1 multivariate linear regression exercise data file) and then attempts to fit a linear model to the dataset using the learning rate, alpha = 0.01. Gradient descent is to make decrements to the parameters (theta vector) 400 times (alpha and num_of_iterations values were given in the problem statement).
I tried a vectorised implementation to obtain the optimum values of parameters but the descent is not converging- the error keeps on increasing.

````
# Imports


```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

# Model Preparation

## Gradient descent


```python
def gradient_descent(m, theta, alpha, num_of_iterations, X, Y):
#     print(m, theta, alpha, num_of_iterations)
    for i in range(num_of_iterations):
        htheta_vector = np.dot(X,theta)
#         print(X.shape, theta.shape, htheta_vector.shape)
        error_vector = htheta_vector - Y
        gradient_vector = (1/m) * (np.dot(X.T, error_vector)) # each element in gradient_vector corresponds to each theta
        theta = theta - alpha * gradient_vector

    return theta
```

# Main


```python
def main():
    df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv', header = None) #loading data
    data = df.values # converting dataframe to numpy array

    X = data[:, 0:2]
#     print(X.shape)
    Y = data[:, -1]

    m = (X.shape)[0] # number of training examples

    Y = Y.reshape(m, 1)

    ones = np.ones(shape = (m,1))
    X_with_bias = np.concatenate([ones, X], axis = 1)

    theta = np.zeros(shape = (3,1)) # two features, so three parameters

    alpha = 0.001
    num_of_iterations = 400

    theta = gradient_descent(m, theta, alpha, num_of_iterations, X_with_bias, Y) # calling gradient descent
#     print('Parameters learned: ' + str(theta))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```
````

**The error:**

```
    /home/krish-thorcode/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
```

> Error values for different iterations:
>
> Iteration 1 [[-399900.]  [-329900.]  [-369000.]  [-232000.] 
>   [-539900.]  [-299900.]  [-314900.]  [-198999.]  [-212000.]  [-242500.]
>   [-239999.]  [-347000.]  [-329999.]  [-699900.]  [-259900.]  [-449900.]
>   [-299900.]  [-199900.]  [-499998.]  [-599000.]  [-252900.]  [-255000.]
>   [-242900.]  [-259900.]  [-573900.]  [-249900.]  [-464500.]  [-469000.]
>   [-475000.]  [-299900.]  [-349900.]  [-169900.]  [-314900.]  [-579900.]
>   [-285900.]  [-249900.]  [-229900.]  [-345000.]  [-549000.]  [-287000.]
>   [-368500.]  [-329900.]  [-314000.]  [-299000.]  [-179900.]  [-299900.]
>   [-239500.]]
>
> Iteration 2 [[1.60749981e+09]  [1.22240841e+09]  [1.83373661e+09] 
>   [1.08189071e+09]  [2.29209231e+09]  [1.51666004e+09]  [1.17198560e+09]
>   [1.09033113e+09]  [1.05440030e+09]  [1.14148964e+09]  [1.48233053e+09]
>   [1.52807496e+09]  [1.44402895e+09]  [3.42143452e+09]  [9.68760976e+08]
>   [1.75723592e+09]  [1.00845873e+09]  [9.44366284e+08]  [1.99332644e+09]
>   [2.31572369e+09]  [1.35010833e+09]  [1.44257442e+09]  [1.22555224e+09]
>   [1.49912323e+09]  [2.97220331e+09]  [8.40383843e+08]  [1.11375611e+09]
>   [1.92992696e+09]  [1.68078878e+09]  [2.01492327e+09]  [1.40503327e+09]
>   [7.64040689e+08]  [1.55867654e+09]  [2.39674784e+09]  [1.38370165e+09]
>   [1.09792232e+09]  [9.46628911e+08]  [1.62895368e+09]  [3.22059730e+09]
>   [1.65193796e+09]  [1.27127807e+09]  [1.70997383e+09]  [1.96141565e+09]
>   [9.16755655e+08]  [6.50928858e+08]  [1.41502023e+09] 
>   [9.19107783e+08]]
>
> Iteration 3 [[-7.42664624e+12]  [-5.64764378e+12]  [-8.47145714e+12] 
>   [-4.99816153e+12]  [-1.05893224e+13]  [-7.00660901e+12] 
>   [-5.41467917e+12]  [-5.03699402e+12]  [-4.87109500e+12] 
>   [-5.27348843e+12]  [-6.84776945e+12]  [-7.05955046e+12] 
>   [-6.67127611e+12]  [-1.58063228e+13]  [-4.47576119e+12] 
>   [-8.11848565e+12]  [-4.65930400e+12]  [-4.36280860e+12] 
>   [-9.20918360e+12]  [-1.06987452e+13]  [-6.23711474e+12] 
>   [-6.66421140e+12]  [-5.66176276e+12]  [-6.92542434e+12] 
>   [-1.37308096e+13]  [-3.88276038e+12]  [-5.14641706e+12] 
>   [-8.91620784e+12]  [-7.76550392e+12]  [-9.30801176e+12] 
>   [-6.49125293e+12]  [-3.52977344e+12]  [-7.20074619e+12] 
>   [-1.10728954e+13]  [-6.39242960e+12]  [-5.07229174e+12] 
>   [-4.37339793e+12]  [-7.52548475e+12]  [-1.48779889e+13] 
>   [-7.63137769e+12]  [-5.87354379e+12]  [-7.89963490e+12] 
>   [-9.06093321e+12]  [-4.23573710e+12]  [-3.00737309e+12] 
>   [-6.53715005e+12]  [-4.24632634e+12]]
>
> Iteration 4 [[3.43099835e+16]  [2.60912608e+16]  [3.91368523e+16] 
>   [2.30907512e+16]  [4.89210695e+16]  [3.23694753e+16]  [2.50149995e+16]
>   [2.32701516e+16]  [2.25037231e+16]  [2.43627199e+16]  [3.16356608e+16]
>   [3.26140566e+16]  [3.08202877e+16]  [7.30228235e+16]  [2.06773403e+16]
>   [3.75061770e+16]  [2.15252802e+16]  [2.01555166e+16]  [4.25450367e+16]
>   [4.94265862e+16]  [2.88145280e+16]  [3.07876502e+16]  [2.61564888e+16]
>   [3.19944145e+16]  [6.34342666e+16]  [1.79377661e+16]  [2.37756683e+16]
>   [4.11915330e+16]  [3.58754545e+16]  [4.30016088e+16]  [2.99886077e+16]
>   [1.63070200e+16]  [3.32663597e+16]  [5.11551035e+16]  [2.95320591e+16]
>   [2.34332215e+16]  [2.02044376e+16]  [3.47666027e+16]  [6.87340617e+16]
>   [3.52558124e+16]  [2.71348846e+16]  [3.64951201e+16]  [4.18601431e+16]
>   [1.95684650e+16]  [1.38936092e+16]  [3.02006457e+16] 
>   [1.96173860e+16]]
>
> Iteration 5 [[-1.58506940e+20]  [-1.20537683e+20]  [-1.80806345e+20] 
>   [-1.06675782e+20]  [-2.26007951e+20]  [-1.49542086e+20] 
>   [-1.15565519e+20]  [-1.07504585e+20]  [-1.03963801e+20] 
>   [-1.12552086e+20]  [-1.46151974e+20]  [-1.50672014e+20] 
>   [-1.42385073e+20]  [-3.37354413e+20]  [-9.55261885e+19] 
>   [-1.73272871e+20]  [-9.94435428e+19]  [-9.31154420e+19] 
>   [-1.96551642e+20]  [-2.28343362e+20]  [-1.33118767e+20] 
>   [-1.42234293e+20]  [-1.20839027e+20]  [-1.47809362e+20] 
>   [-2.93056729e+20]  [-8.28697695e+19]  [-1.09839996e+20] 
>   [-1.90298660e+20]  [-1.65739180e+20]  [-1.98660937e+20] 
>   [-1.38542837e+20]  [-7.53359691e+19]  [-1.53685556e+20] 
>   [-2.36328850e+20]  [-1.36433652e+20]  [-1.08257943e+20] 
>   [-9.33414495e+19]  [-1.60616452e+20]  [-3.17540981e+20] 
>   [-1.62876527e+20]  [-1.25359067e+20]  [-1.68601941e+20] 
>   [-1.93387537e+20]  [-9.04033523e+19]  [-6.41863754e+19] 
>   [-1.39522421e+20]  [-9.06293597e+19]]
>
> Iteration 83 [[-1.09904300e+306]  [-8.35774743e+305] 
>   [-1.25366087e+306]  [-7.39660179e+305]  [-1.56707622e+306] 
>   [-1.03688320e+306]  [-8.01299137e+305]  [-7.45406868e+305] 
>   [-7.20856058e+305]  [-7.80404831e+305]  [-1.01337710e+306] 
>   [-1.04471781e+306]  [-9.87258464e+305]  [-2.33912159e+306] 
>   [-6.62352000e+305]  [-1.20142586e+306]  [-6.89513844e+305] 
>   [-6.45636555e+305]  [-1.36283437e+306]  [-1.58326931e+306] 
>   [-9.23008472e+305]  [-9.86212994e+305]  [-8.37864174e+305] 
>   [-1.02486897e+306]  [-2.03197378e+306]  [-5.74595914e+305] 
>   [-7.61599955e+305]  [-1.31947793e+306]  [-1.14918934e+306] 
>   [-1.37745963e+306]  [-9.60617469e+305]  [-5.22358639e+305] 
>   [-1.06561287e+306]  [-1.63863846e+306]  [-9.45992963e+305] 
>   [-7.50630445e+305]  [-6.47203628e+305]  [-1.11366977e+306] 
>   [-2.20174077e+306]  [-1.12934050e+306]  [-8.69204879e+305] 
>   [-1.16903893e+306]  [-1.34089535e+306]  [-6.26831680e+305] 
>   [-4.45050460e+305]  [-9.67409627e+305]  [-6.28398753e+305]]
>
> Iteration84 [[inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf] 
>   [inf] [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]
>   [inf] [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf] 
>   [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf] 
>   [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]  [inf]]

Answer (score 5):

Please try feature normalization to overcome this problem. It's just that the feature values are big numbers and the cost function(squared error) increases at a fast rate when the values are big. As a general rule perform mean normalization and feature scaling when you are trying to minimize a non-linear cost function.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked!! I completely had forgotten about scaling! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do feature normalization. Asumming [this](https://github.com/AvaisP/machine-learning-programming-assignments-coursera-andrew-ng/blob/master/machine-learning-ex1/ex1/ex1data2.txt) is your dataset, First dimension of X is in the thousands, second is in the tens and Y is in the hundred thousands. 
Use `sklearn.preprocessing.scale` to make all columns of data and target to [0,1] or you can use this 
dirty normalization :

```
 X[:,0] = X[:,0] / np.max( X[:,0])

 X[:,1] = X[:,1] / np.max( X[:,1])

 Y = Y / np.max(Y)
```

I reran your code with these normalizers. Theta converges to 
`[ 0.81705857], [ 0.98398577], [ 0.98398577]`

Try to provide a link to the data files or pandas data frame summary for future questions.

Comment: It worked after doing feature normlisation. Thanks.. :)